# Prevent second line hanging in questions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

How do I prevent the second line to be indented as in the following example?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setcounter{question}{100}
        \question This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long question
        \begin{choices}
            \choice one
            \choice two
        \end{choices} 
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I want the second line to be aligned horizontally with the "T" from "This".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to adjust the `\labelwidth` using `\questionshook`.

```
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{9999}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\mylen}%
   }
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{9999}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\mylen}%
 }

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long question
        \begin{choices}
            \choice one
            \choice two
        \end{choices}
        \setcounter{question}{100}
        \question This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long question
        \begin{choices}
            \choice one
            \choice two
        \end{choices}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with this solution the label will go out of the page margin, which I do not want. You can see it by using the showframe package

Comment: @Mishi: Change the `\leftmargin` value: say, `\setlength{\leftmargin}{\dimexpr\mylen+1ex}%`.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to edit my comment, thanks!